# Insert between the tag of the current line in Vim

Tags: vim

For instance, I have:

```
<div></div>(my cursor is blinking in this line)
```

How do I automatically position my cursor between the tags in insertion mode? I'm assuming there is only one tag for the line.

Comment: use `f<i` or `F<i` depending on which side of the tag the cursor is on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a text object. If you're in insert mode, leave insert mode. Your cursor is probably now on the final > in the div tag. Type `cit` (change inside tag) to remove all text within the tag (if any) and enter insert mode there. If you didn't actually want to remove anything, you can restore it with CTRL-R followed by - to paste the contents of the - register. See `:help text-objects`, there are many more and they are one of Vim's most useful features.

Or, using the `%` motion, start the same way. If you're in insert mode, leave insert mode. Your cursor is now on >. Press `%` to jump to the matching < on the end tag. Then press i to enter insert mode.

The advantage of the first method is that it works from anywhere on the  tag or end tag.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one tag on each line and no other "<" characters, you can use `02f<i`. `0` to bring you to the first character, `2f<` to bring you to the second "<" character, and then `i` to bring you into insert mode.